# command/object option window - how to recover

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

The small window which opens up when i execute a command goes off if i click anywhere else in the window and is not recoverable (screenshot attached). how can i get this back.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a noob so forgive me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, you can, but not for the operation you just completed (by clicking).

This command window appears after doing an operation (scale, add mesh, in your case move, etc) and allows you to set the parameters of the operation precisely by inputting numbers. When you click anywhere you complete the operation and can't adjust it anymore. But you can ctrl+z and try it again of course.

So if you want this window to reappear you select the object and hit G (for move), but then the move parameters will be based off the current position. If you put in numbers and click, you can hit G again, but now the move parameters will be based off the new position.
I hope this helps.